# Passing a column of data frame as an argument to a function inside lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda

I am trying to pass the values of my data frame using a lambda function to call another function in the following way:

```
df_final_data['beta'] =  df_final_data.apply(lambda x: capm(x['Excess_ret'], x['Mkt_Exc_ret'), axis = 1)

def camp(x,y):
  ## Code for linear regression returning beta
```

This is passing row-wise value of my data frame. Instead I want to pass the complete column of Excess_ret and MKt_Exc_ret in the function .
How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

With the following toy dataframe and function:

```py
import pandas as pd

def capm(x, y):
    return x + y

df_final_data = pd.DataFrame({"Excess_ret": [1, 2, 3], "Mkt_Exc_ret": [4, 8, 16]})
```

Here is one way to pass the complete columns `Excess_ret` and `MKt_Exc_ret` in the function using [tolist](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```py
print(capm(df_final_data["Excess_ret"].tolist(), df_final_data["Mkt_Exc_ret"].tolist()))
# Output
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 16]
```

Which merges the two columns, as expected here.